# Moving files around in XCode and IOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, ios7

I move some files into a subdirectory but now I get linking errors saying files can't be found. Where do I go (like a projects file) to tell XCODE where to look for the new files?

I tried removing everything and adding them back in but I still get missing files even though they are one directory in and added to the project.

Comment: And my .app and .xctest files are red now too...

Comment: can put the linker error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a file in left panel, open inspector panel on the right and choose a path to file there.

Note: it's more efficient to do that if your files are organized into folders; that way, you only need to change the path to folder and the elements are relative to it.